# multi path url as dynamic route after certain url path Express JS?

Tags: node.js, express, backend, mern

I am trying to catch a multi path url as param.

Example:

My router is:

```
router.get("/assets/:file", someFunction)
```

What I am trying to do if  some one put this as url:

```
localhost:8000/assets/xyz.pdf
```

It fine! But Is this possible that if someone enters this:

```
localhost:8000/assets/pdfs/xyz.pdf
```

I want to capture `file` param as `pdfs/xyz.pdf`. Currently its showing `cannot GET /assets/pdf/xyz.pdf` as it's treating it as a seperate router.

Please hlep. Thank you!

Comment: Try `router.get("/assets/*", someFunction)` and inside `someFunction` evaluate `req.params[0]`.